# Cannot get YouTube embed to load video on my website (latest upload by channel)

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I got the code to do it off this website, But I am having an error with YouTube when i upload the website and try and watch the video. An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: ikfCEyIcFj-kfzFc) 
Learn More - The code I used is this:

```
<iframe width="1197" height="604" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=ozrustnetwork" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Expect result is video to play, instead I get this message: An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: ikfCEyIcFj-kfzFc) 
Learn More

Comment: <iframe width="1197" height="604" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=ozrustnetwork" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Is using PHP an option for you? You can either (1) sign-up for developer account on Youtube and use their API for latest channel upload or else (2) Use something like PHP to get source code text from their uploads web-page. First link is latest video..

Answer (score 0):

It's because that's embedded so you need to use a format like:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/` + `VIDEO-ID`

Example (video-id is `3daK_doWl0g`) :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3daK_doWl0g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It should embed an example video about a car game.

Comment: As you can see I have just the video link in src not the whole embeded thing